# Logistic regression coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I am doing logistic regression with 3 attributes. According to my data set I am expecting all coefficients to be positive. But it gives me both positive and negative coefficients. Is it possible to have all positive coefficients using logistic regression.

Comment: Are you expecting the coefficients on the log odds scale to be positive?

Comment: no, i want the logistic regression coefficients to be positive

Comment: Do you have any regression software that allows setting bounds on the parameters? If so, you could set all of the lower bounds at zero.

Comment: Can you post the output of your software?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to have all positive coefficients in logistic regression.

That doesn't say very much, if a covariable $x$ have a negative coefficient you can just replace that covariable by $-x$ and get a positive coefficient ... you would get a more useful answer if you told us about your real problem, your data, the context and research questions.